# In perforce, how to remove a symlink to a directory and add files in the same directory?

Tags: perforce, symlink

This can be done like this:
1. p4 delete dir,
   p4 submit;
2. p4 add dir/file,
   p4 submit;
Is there a way to do this in one go? 
I don't want to do p4 submit in step 1 because not having that directory will break things at my end.

Comment: Did you try it? That is, did you try removing the submit from step 1?

Comment: I tried it now. It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not seem to be anything preventing this:

```
C:\Perforce\test\dir>p4 opened
//stream/main/dir#1 - delete default change (symlink)
//stream/main/dir/bar#1 - add default change (text)
//stream/main/dir/foo#1 - add default change (text)

C:\Perforce\test\dir>p4 submit -d "presto"
Submitting change 106.
Locking 3 files ...
delete //stream/main/dir#2
add //stream/main/dir/bar#1
add //stream/main/dir/foo#1
Change 106 submitted.
```